# Properties of the gas in a Geiger-Muller tube

Tags: experimental-physics, nuclear-physics, radiation, experimental-technology

Why does the gas filling a Geiger-Muller tube have to be inert and at low-pressure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interactions in the gas produce a microscopic cloud of electrons that needs to drift to the electrode in order to produce a signal. If you have a gas that can absorb the electrons away, that doesn't work. So the gas needs to be both inert (check its electronegativity) and low-density (check the effective electron drift length).